# Custom Tab not showing on product page. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, websites, ecommerce-tracking

I am making a **custom tab** for the product page on Magento 2.

I followed this tutorial

> https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/.

At the end, the custom tab is showing up in more information section rather than a separate tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar thing using following steps :

Added **catalog_product_view.xml** in my custom theme `app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.ingredients" template="product/view/ingredients.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Ingredients</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Added **ingredients.phtml** in **app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view**

```
<?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
echo $product->getData('ingredients');
```

I hope this will help you.